# AE - Creating speed/motion lines?

Tags: after-effects

https://gyazo.com/6cb8bcf6193716407790a11205bd060c

Any idea how I can create this effect in illustrator on a (rectangle) shape? Are there any effect presets for it?

[The gif is from here.](https://youtu.be/peVpXjb4bJ8?t=7)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you asking about a motion graphic (AE) or static, vector graphic (Iillustrator)? Please be more specific or you will get the snarky, but true answer that you just use animation.

Comment: You mean "Animation™"

Comment: I've added a solution below.

Comment: related: https://video.stackexchange.com/a/16513/6685

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good tutorial explaining this.